# jQuery width returns wrong value when table is too small

Tags: jquery, iphone, width

I have a table with a liquid width. Im trying to use jQuery to get the width of a table cell (one has a class of calAv), and make all the cells have the same height so they are all square.

The following code seems to work fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

```
function calHeightSet () { 
    calWidth = $('.calMonth .calAv').width();
    //alert (calWidth);
    $('.calMonth tr').css('height',calWidth);
}
```

The only mobile device ive tested with so far is an iPhone 3G, where it appears no height value is added. If I uncomment the alert, then the alert's value in pixels is the height of the table cells. However this height is the same as if I completely remove this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the jQuery [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function:

```
$('.calMonth tr').height(calWidth);
```

Alternatively, may be you need to be more specific and include `td`:

```
$('.calMonth tr td').height(calWidth);
```

Comment: Dont know why my code didnt work but this seems to have fixed it, Thanks.